# IntelliJ Run Configuration Broken by an Incompatible Plugin I Can't Uninstall?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

I had been developing an application on a trial version of IntelliJ 2016 Ultimate. Since the trial version ran out, I resumed work using the Community Edition. However, trying to launch my application yielded the following error:

```
Unknown run configuration type  #com.intellij.j2ee.web.tomcat.TomcatRunConfigurationFactory
```

"No problem" I thought, just an incompatible plugin that was installed with Ultimate that I don't really need anyway. I opened the Plugins section of the Preferences menu, but I can't find the plugin in question. Below is a partial screenshot of the plugin list where I would expect to see the plugin listed in the error message.

[image: Missing plugin]

The configuration can also not be edited from the Run/Debug Configurations menu, but lists the Run Configuration error as: "Broken configuration due to unavailable plugin or invalid configuration data."

Am I really unable to uninstall the Ultimate plugin preventing my run configuration from working from the Community Edition? What can I do to fix this if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the community edition of IDEA will not load and run plugins that are not compatible with it. Moreover, by default, the community edition uses a different configuration directory than the Ultimate edition. So unless you modified the config directory to use, the community version should not be picking up the Ultimate Edition's plugins. Based on the error you show, I think the issue is you simply need to delete that Run configuration. The error is saying that that Run configuration wants to use a Plugin (The Tomcat Plugin) that is not available (i.e. not installed).

If you still want to confirm what plugins are installed, you can manually uninstall a plugin by removing it from the `plugins` directory. Note that some plugins are simply a standalone JAR, in the `plugins` directory, others are sub-directories within the plugins directory. Just delete the JAR or sub-directory.

That `plugins` directory is the idea `config` directory. See [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) for information on its location. On windows for example, by default it will be:

- Ultimate: `C:\Users\UserName\.IntelliJIdea2016\config\plugins`
- Community: `C:\Users\UserName\..IdeaIC2016\config\plugins`

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention... *bundled* plugins are in `${idea-install-directory}/plugins`. So for the ultimate edition, the Tomcat plugin is in `${idea-install-directory}/plugins/Tomcat`. That is why, as you mentioned in your comment below, you are not seeing that plugin in the user installed plugin directory I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm reluctant to delete the configuration unless I have to - I didn't modify the config to my knowledge. I'm on Mac OS X, and navigated to ~/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1, but the only contents are a couple of xml files: extensions.xml and availables.xml. In the Ultimate Edition directory in the same folder, I can see an amazon-ec2 plugin folder, with a bunch of jars, and the fileWatcher plugin I previously configured, but nothing matching the plugin in the error. Do you think I'd gain anything by deleting the Ultimate Edition entirely?

Comment: If you want to preserve the run configuration before you delete it, you can back it up. If you have shared the run/debug configuration (via the "share" option in the upper right corner), the configuration file will be in `${project_directory}/.idea/runConfigurations/${runConfigurationName}.xml`. If it is not shared, it will be an element in the file  `${project_directory}/.idea/workspace.xml`. I posted an edit to my answer about an additional plugin location for bundled plugins. That is where you would see the Tomcat Plugin.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for that! I just booted up Ultimate again (I can use it for 30 mins at a time) and the configuration is also broken/un-editable there, though the error is a bit more descriptive:
           Unknown features (Run Configuration[#com.intellij.j2ee.web.tomcat.TomcatRunConfigurationFactory], Artifact[exploded-war]) covered by disabled plugins detected.
           Enable plugins...
           Ignore Unknown Features

Comment: One final comment - I found the offending plugins in almost the path you specified. For me, it was in `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins`

Comment: Was having a similar problem, and found out the Kotlin plugin needed to be uninstalled and reinstalled. You would think IntelliJ products would play better together than this. Oy!

Answer (score 10):

[image: How to update plugins]

It's have been a long time since this question was launched but it might be useful for new searches. 
*I got the same error with Dart and Flutter*.
Just go to **Menu >> File >> Settings**. Then type plugins on the search box. **Check if your plugins need to be updated** (in my case Dart and Flutter). I the screenshot I had clicked in the "update" green button. So it turns into "**Restart IDE**" text. It should fix the problem once you restart the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

updating flutter and android studio worked in my 
case

Answer (score 0):

Simple upgrade Dart plugin..
Go to Settings/Plugins/Browse Repositories and search dart (Language) and upgrade

this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar worded issue "Run Configuration Error: Broken configuration due to unavailable plugin or invalid configuration data."

In the bottom right part of the Rider IDE, you will see a popup that says

"Plugin supporting feature (Run Configuration[UNITY_ATTACH_AND_PLAY]) is currently disabled."

Click enable plugins, and restart when Rider asks you to do so.

If this does not work, remember that one possible reason is the issues with macOS indexing (my Macbook started to malfunction after its battery hit 0). A way to check is to try and search a file from the top right corner(). If you can not find existing files, this means macOS messed up with indexing.

To solve it, click Apple icon on top left side and go to System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Privacy Tab -> Add all folders to the "won't index" box -> Remove everything you have added so they get reindexed.

https://www.techradar.com/how-to/software/operating-systems/how-to-fix-a-mac-s-broken-find-function-1298964

Lastly, go to Rider and hit File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.